# Update sequence in oracle from vb.net

Tags: oracle, vb.net, updates

I try to increment a field in a table... but I've an error.

```vb
Public Function GetConnexion() As OracleConnection
    Dim str = New OracleConnectionStringBuilder With {
           .Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ORACLE_MDP_PDM).ToString,
           .UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ORACLE_USER_PDM).ToString,
           .DataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ORACLE_DTSRC_PDM).ToString
       }
    Return New OracleConnection With {.ConnectionString = str.ConnectionString}
End Function

Private sub getIdObject() As Double
    Dim con As OracleConnection = GetConnexion()
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand With {.Connection = con}
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE COUNTER SET VALUE=VALUE+1 where REFERENCE='ID_OBJECT';"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Sub
```

And the errors:

> Message:ORA-00911: caractère non valide
> Exception:Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00911: caractère non valide
> à OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
> à OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF)
> à Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> à Cotix.getIdObject() dans XXXX.vb:ligne 60
> à Cotix.InsertMapping(List`1 GeneralDatas) dans XXXX.vb:ligne 77
> à Cotix._Default.Defrag(MonFormEditPhoto MesDonnees) dans XXXX.vb:ligne 36

When I copy/Paste in oracleDevelopper tools... it's work...
When I try to select

```vb
Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim con As OracleConnection = GetConnexion()
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand With {.Connection = con}
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter With {.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, .Value = "ID_OBJECT"})
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT VALUE  FROM COUNTER where REFERENCE = :1"
    Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    HelperJournal.WriteEntry("NewIdObject", dr.Item("VALUE").ToString)'Write in file :4085 the good value...
    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()
End Sub
```

It's work...
What I don't see????
Thanks for your help

Comment: I would remove that semicolon. It is used to separate statements and you don't have multiple statements

Comment: Learn about `Using` blocks. Also, `Sub` doesn't have a return type.

Comment: Working on an answer, and I have weird stuff going on in the answer box leading me to suspect there is a misplaced Unicode character in here: something unprintable, a wrong diactric, or invisible whitespace of some kind.

Comment: I Try too remove semicolon but I've error messge saying missing important.... Then the semicolon is the syntaxe for Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Public Function GetConnexion() As OracleConnection
    Static str As New OracleConnectionStringBuilder With {
           .Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ORACLE_MDP_PDM).ToString,
           .UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ORACLE_USER_PDM).ToString,
           .DataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(ORACLE_DTSRC_PDM).ToString
       }
    Return New OracleConnection With {.ConnectionString = str.ConnectionString}
End Function

' Note the better name and lack of return type
Private Sub updateIdObject() 
    Using con As OracleConnection = GetConnexion(), _ 
          cmd As New OracleCommand("UPDATE COUNTER SET VALUE=VALUE+1 where REFERENCE='ID_OBJECT';", con)

        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    Using con As OracleConnection = GetConnexion(), _
          cmd As new OracleCommand("SELECT VALUE  FROM COUNTER where REFERENCE = :1", con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter With {.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, .Value = "ID_OBJECT"})
        con.Open()

        Using dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
           dr.Read()
           HelperJournal.WriteEntry("NewIdObject", dr.Item("VALUE").ToString)'Write in file :4085 the good value...
        End Using
   End Using
End Sub
```

In working on this answer there was some weird stuff happening in the answer box, such that I suspect there is a misplaced Unicode character in here: something unprintable, a wrong diactric, or invisible whitespace of some kind, that might be throwing off the Oracle code. You may need to re-type the SQL.